# Can't click on the comment button on Twitter using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I have been developing a bot for twitter and I came to a problem. I can't click the comment button:

[image]

No matter which XPATH I copy I always get this error message:

[image]

This is the code for the comment button:

```
comment_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id__pm1tufstyp"]/div[1]/div')
```

Can somebody please assist me in finding the right XPATH or what ever for the comment button?

Thank you. :)

P.S. Here is the entire code just put your email, username and password if you are going to run the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

URL = "https://twitter.com/"

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
]

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))

accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')
accept_cookies.click()

sign_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[5]/a/div')
sign_in.click()
time.sleep(2)

email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
email.click()
email.send_keys('YOUR EMAIL')
time.sleep(1)

next_button_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div')
next_button_1.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Twitter sometimes asks for username sometimes doesn't
try:
    user_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
    user_name.click()
    user_name.send_keys('YOUR USERNAME')

    next_button_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div')
    next_button_2.click()
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    print("Username input field not found. Twitter may not have requested it.")

password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')
password.click()
password.send_keys('YOUR PASSWORD')

sing_in_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div')
sing_in_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/header/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/a[2]/div')
search_button.click()
time.sleep(1)

search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/input')
search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys('elon musk')
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, 300);")

time.sleep(2)

comment_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id__pm1tufstyp"]/div[1]/div')
comment_button.click()
time.sleep(1)

reply_message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
reply_message.click()
reply_message.send_keys('hello')

reply = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]')
reply.click()
time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: `please assist me in finding the right XPATH` — how we're supposed to do this without actual code?

Comment: @Alderven Code for the button is added in the post.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the code in the question does not constitute a [mre].

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I will give you the entire code.

Comment: Thanks, but any code that asks volunteers to 1.) run an untrusted script and 2.) input their login information for a site isn't minimal. I will be keeping my close vote.

Comment: I don't want to put my login information, that is way I have written that.